# How to modify the GNU linker to have separate 'RWE ' PT_LOAD segment

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, executable, elf

I have a program which when converted to binary using deafult options I get this.

```
>readelf -lW /tmp/sample

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x13e33f 0x13e33f R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x13e510 0x000000000073e510 0x000000000073e510 0x005160 0x007cc8 RW  0x200000
```

I want to have a separate LOAD segment with RWE permissions after the LOAD segment with RW (i.e. data segment) shown above. One approach to do this is to modify the custom GNU linker script to pick my new sections and put them in a separate segment after the bss segment. This will cause it to appear as third LOAD segment.

Adding this after bss end in linker script

```
 .my_section = .;
 .my_section : { *(.my_section)}
```

This is how it appears

```
>readelf -lW /tmp/sample

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x13e33f 0x13e33f R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x13e510 0x000000000073e510 0x000000000073e510 0x005160 0x007cc8 RW  0x200000
  LOAD           0x13f000 0x000000000073f000 0x000000000073f000 0x0d6b00 0x0d6b00 RW  0x200000
```

How to get executable permissions as well in this segment? What changes I need to do to the linker script?

Comment: I guess it's because your .my_section section does not have SHF_EXECINSTR.

Comment: I think you need to play with `PHDRS` https://github.com/cirosantilli/assembly-cheat/blob/d60f55ed7dcf54dd7083a2d4fdcfd6b79b15c084/linker-scripts/flags.ld#L17